# ERROR - SQL Error '[Cache ODBC][State : S1000][Native Code 29]

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I have been using the query below and it was working fine but now it's giving a SQL error.
There were no changes made that could cause this to stop working.
There is no Field 'APPLICATIONID' in the table.

```
QueueSQL=select distinct (convert(char(5),SkillsetID)+'='+Skillset) from iagentbySkillsetStat where ApplicationID > 10000

QueueMappingSQL=SELECT DISTINCT (convert(char(5),SkillsetID)+'='+Skillset), SkillsetID FROM iagentbySkillsetStat iagentbySkillsetStat WHERE (iagentbySkillsetStat.ApplicationID>10000)
```

DB- Intersystems Cache

Error details for the log files are below.

```
14/09/2016 11:20:05 a.m. > ERROR - SQL Error '[Cache ODBC][State : S1000][Native Code 29]
[C:\xlink\xlink Compiled Package\Xlink Application\Isps_Ul.exe]
[SQLCODE: <-29>:<Field not found in the applicable tables>]
[Cache Error: <<SYNTAX>errdone+2^%qaqqt>]
[Details: <Prepare>]
[%msg: < SQL ERROR #29: Field 'APPLICATIONID' not found in the applicable tables^select distinct ( convert ( char ( 5 ) , SkillsetID ) + :%qpar(1) + Skillset ) from iagentbySkillsetStat where ApplicationID >>]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Question was also asked at I[nterSystems Developer Community](https://community.intersystems.com/post/error-sql-error-cache-odbcstate-s1000native-code-29), where I noticed that table names are different. So, the answer is, that table name is suddenly changed somehow.